# Extracting body's attribute, by also keeping the relative tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to traverse a HTML body, in order to find all the `<h1>` tags:

```
Element body = docJSoup.body();
Elements mainCmp = body.select("h1");
```

So, considering this body's fragment:

```
<h1><span style='mso-bookmark:_Toc283737133'><span
style='mso-spacerun:yes'></span><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'></span><a
name="_Toc35343186"></a><a name="_Toc264704629"></a><span style='mso-bookmark:
_Toc35343186'>3<span style='mso-tab-count:1'></span>Aspetti metodologici</span></span></h1>
```

I'm going to get this:

```
<span style="mso-bookmark:_Toc283737133"><span style="mso-spacerun:yes"></span><span style="mso-spacerun:yes"></span><a name="_Toc35343186"></a><a name="_Toc264704629"></a><span style="mso-bookmark:
_Toc35343186">3<span style="mso-tab-count:1"></span>Aspetti metodologici</span></span>
```

By the way, I would like to maintain also the `<h1>` tag into the result.
And the `<h1>` tag itself could also have other attributes, so I cannot just concatenate `"<h1>"` to the resulting string.
Is there a way to keep it using JSoup methods?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Using the parent attribute might help

Comment: @NadirBaoun: Thank you, but Constantin's answer is the straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`outerHtml()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#outerHtml()) will give you the node's markup including its own opening and closing tags.